# How to POST multidimensional array in a Laravel test?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm unable to POST multidimensional arrays in my Laravel tests. Single dimensional arrays POST fine. Maybe I should be using some other function using json_encode, but I can't find anything to support this.

**It is important that I am able to POST the data structure below, I have added in my seeJSONStructure() assertion to better illustrate the data structure.**

Here is an example of my test:

```
$this->json('POST', '/endpoint', [
    'foo' =>  'foo',
    'bar' =>   [
        [
            'foo' => 'foo',
            'bar' => 'bar'
        ]
     ]
])
->assertResponseStatus(200)
->seeJsonStructure([
    '*' => [
        'foo', 
        'bar' => [
            '*' => [
                'foo',
                'bar'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

This gives me the error

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Argument #2 (No Value) of PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertArrayHasKey() must be an array or ArrayAccess
```

Removing the nested array prevents the error, but there must be a way to POST multidimensional arrays.

The below works fine:

```
$this->json('POST', '/endpoint', [
    'foo' =>  'foo',
    'bar' =>  'bar'
])
->assertResponseStatus(200)
```

Comment: check here 'bar => 'bar' add single quote

Comment: `'foo => 'foo',` & `'bar => 'bar'` Is typo error?

Comment: Sorry the missing single quotes were a typo in my example and not the real issue

Comment: @Elliot I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

replace your test code with below:

```
$this->json('POST', '/endpoint', [
    'foo' =>  'foo',
    'bar' =>   [
        [
            'foo' => 'foo',
            'bar' => 'bar'
        ]
     ]
])
->assertResponseStatus(200)
```

Comment: What changed in your answer?

Comment: @Nawin: I'm not getting your point, can you please clarify 'Now same as what Elliot gives'

Comment: Sorry, the single quotes were a typo in my example and not apart of the issue. I have now updated my question

Comment: @Elliot: Sounds good, let me check it as this is not the mistake

Comment: @Elliot: There is many possibility for this error, first you need to check the end point is correct or not?

Comment: The endpoint logic is correct. The second snippet of code in the example works fine. It's when I pass a multidimensional array I get an error stating I need to pass an array

Comment: @Elliot: `assertArrayHasKey('key', Object);`, Hope the second param you passed as object as correct way.

Comment: Updated the question to show the data structure i'm trying to POST

Answer (score 0):

As per the [document](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html)  `assertArrayHasKey()` need to give the key for an array... Try like this Not tested...And check also your `endpoint` path was correct.

```
$this->json('POST', '/endpoint', [
    'foo' =>  'foo',
    'bar' =>   [    
            'baz'=>[
                    'foo' => 'foo',
                    'bar' => 'bar'
                    ]
     ]
])
->assertResponseStatus(200)
```

**Edited**:
New code for the JsonStructure

```
$this->json('POST', '/endpoint', [
    'foo',
    'bar' =>   [    
            '*'=>[
                    'foo',
                    'bar'
                    ]
     ]
])
```

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that, but my API is expecting bar to be an array of objects. I updated my question to include my key structure assertion so it's clearer. How can I POST this data structure?

Comment: @Elliot you are asking like jsonStructure right then this could be work